# Importing all components in one module or creating multiple modules with lazy loading! Which is better?

Tags: angular, performance, lazy-loading, angular-components, angular-module

With the angular framework, I am working on developing a view which displays different layouts.
We have a side navigation bar. When a user clicks on one of the entries, a view from the corresponding component is displayed while the side navigation bar remains at its position and provides space for layouts to be displayed.
The sidenav also contains such entries which have sub-entries, each subentry having its own component. 
So, for better performance (fast), shall I create multiple modules for each parent menu so that I can lazy load any required module when needed. Or is it better to import all the components in one module itself?
 The menus named child have no submenus, only the parents have submenus! The blank space in the right will display the layout corresponding the components related to the child we click on.
 Should I have a separate module for every parent to lazyload or just one module would be fine?[image]

Comment: https://angular.io/guide/lazy-loading-ngmodules explains lazy-loading and what it is for.

Comment: @MikeS., My question is that if I put components in multiple modules rather than in a single module, does this tradeoff between number of components per module and number of total module hold any sense??
I am worried about if increasing the number of modules may affect the performance of the app to an extent that the effect of lazyloading might become obsolete.